# How to update cookie expiration time with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want sliding time for expiration time of cookie.
This can be done by getting cookie and again setting with new expiration time and deleting previous cookie. But , I want to know better way than this . I need some good solution.

Comment: You have to read the cookie, change the time and write it back.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am trying to read cookie value than deleting old cookie and again setting this cookie with same name... as this work solves my issue .. but its tedious work.. I want to optimize it , and want to know are there any other way to avoid this..,...

Comment: @DanD. I am doing process as mentioned in above comment, but want to find some better way....

Comment: you should check this beautiful blog by Jon Skeet:- http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Try this blog http://thinkclay.com/technology/add-edit-delete-cookies-with-javascript might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "sliding time" I'm assuming you want the cookie to renew itself whenever the visitor reloads the page. Just reset the cookie every time the page loads (i.e. every time the JavaScript code is executed).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

However if you're looking for something more long term with more capacity then I would recommend using `localStorage`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Comment: thanks for your response, but this is not what I am looking for. If you fins some other solution than I am waiting....

Comment: Your current way of doing it (reading the cookie and rewriting it) is the best method IMO. If you find that it is too tedious, put the code in a function and call it wherever you need to reset the cookie.